# Bootstrap 3 elements remain small on mobile on google-apps-script html service

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-apps-script

I'm using bootstrap 3 along with angularjs (with angular for bootstrap) for an html5 application running on google apps script.

I expected Bootstrap to be responsive by default, but for my surprise a very simple form is remaining small on my mobile device. Text, buttons and input fields are so small that they are almost unusable. I'm writting some CSS rules for mobile screens, but I'm not sure if I should. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Here is the form. I have removed some extra stuff to make it simple, but bootstrap makes any single form a big monster:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<base target="_top">    

<?!= include('css'); ?>
</head>
<body ng-app='Gestor'>

<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="ExampleController">

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-4">
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="Concepto" class="col-md-4">Concepto:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8 text-left"><input type="text" ng-model="data.concepto" class="form-control"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
<fieldset class="form-group">

  <label class="col-md-4" for="pvp" >Precio:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group">
          <a class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="increase('pvp',-5)">-5</a>
          <input type="number" ng-model="data.pvp" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
          <a class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="increase('pvp',5)">+5</a>
          </div>
  </div>

  <label  class="col-md-4 " for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="input-group">
          <a class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="increase('cantidad',-5)">-5</a>
          <input type="number" ng-model="data.cantidad" class="form-control">
          <a class="input-group-addon btn btn-default" role="button" ng-click="increase('cantidad',5)">+5</a>
       </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">    
<fieldset class="form-group">

  <label class="col-md-4" for="Category">Categoría:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <select ng-model="data.category" class="form-control form-control-lg" ng-options="option for option in formValues.availableOptions" ></select>
  </div>

  <label class="col-md-4" for="Fecha">Fecha:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="data.fecha" is-open="datepicker.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
              <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> </i></button></span>
            </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-12">    
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <button ng-click="formValues.submitStatus ===0 ? submit() : reset()" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':(formValues.submitStatus===0),'btn-success':(formValues.submitStatus===1),'btn-danger':(formValues.submitStatus<0)}" type="submit">{{formValues.submitStatus===0 ? 'Register' : 'Reset'}}</button>
    </fieldset>
    </div>

    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!-- MAIN APP CODE -->
<?!= include('app.js'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Here is an image that shows what I want to achieve. As you can see, input and label elements are quite big, but that is because the custom CSS styles that I made. I expected this to be automatic on Bootstrap. If you take a look at the bottom, you can see a very small button, that is how the entire form is displayed without my custom styles.

[.. Removed image ..]

EDIT2:
Here is another screenshot added. This time is a much simpler form, which was directly taken from here:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=vertical-form-layout

As you can see, it looks awful
[image]

**EDIT3:**

I have added the tag google apps script, because it should be a problem with how google apps scripts serves the webpage on the Iframe. I have updated the plunk provided by @Satej to make it work properly with angular, but it works exactly as I expected:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ze4DEQDxr3Hd8SVtdifZ?p=preview

I have opened the plunker on my mobile device, and it works flawlessly, no issues so far as you can see on the following screenshot:

[image: Expected appearance]
So the question is, what does google apps script when it serves the HTML file to make it display so small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

The problem was the view-port meta tag. It was being removed by CAJA, or whatever sanitization is applied to IFRAME mode.

There was a bug about this, where people pointed this exact problem:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

And on that same thread, someone linked to a solution:

https://plus.google.com/+MarcoColomboMow/posts/GXgRCh98HTu

Finally, it was just a matter of adding the following to the html template when serving it (on the doGet function)

```
return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong.

You have to explicity state the styling for small and extra small screens if you want them to take a particular column size.

This is done by using the `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*` classes.

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure that is correct. As I said, I expected Bootstrap to be mobile first, so it should be displayed correctly by default on mobile unless yo specify something else. Take a look to the screenshot that I have attached to the question, that is what I wanted, but to achieve that I have to style classes myself. By default, on mobile input elements are 100% wide and display block, which is what I wanted, but they are so small , specially in height, that they are unusable.

Comment: Can you setup a plunker?

Comment: Isn't this how you want it?[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbrm1zj6dGlkOnCErC4E?p=preview)

Comment: Hello Satej, thank you for the Plunkr. I have updated the description with it